# How to set the div with percentage height and width in my case?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to create a dynamic `width` and `height` contains that is based on the percentage of the browser viewport.

I have something like

```
<body>
  <div id='wrapper' >
       <img src='test.png'/>
  </div>
</body>
```

css

```
#wrapper{
   width:80%;
   height:80%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The reason I use percentage as `width` and `height` is because I want to make the `wrapper` being responsive for small screen so I can't set it as pixels. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't understand - is the issue with the image or are you just asking for the best way to create a responsive layout?

Comment: The wrapper width is not 80% of the screen. I did this because I want my wrapper div shown as 80% of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I copied your code it worked fine (though I changed the background to black so I could see the div). I put a picture in and the div expanded accordingly. So, I'm guessing your issue is with the img. At the end of the day the following css worked for me:

```
#wrapper{
   width:80%;
   height:80%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   background-color: #000;
}

#wrapper img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

If you want to see an example (with rainbow cat in it), see the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q5MGp/. Good luck!

**Note** - If you want to force the Height to be 100%, you have to make sure the body height is 100% (div's size to their container or contents). So add the following line to your css file:

```
body,html{height:100%;}
```

That should help with the height!